# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found

Tags: widgets, fatal-error

Anybody got a solution for this?

I can't reach admin page or most of the other pages except I can reach the home page.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-links.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/default-widgets.php(14): require_once() #1 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/functions.php(3782): require_once('/home1/thehub/p...') #2 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): wp_maybe_load_widgets('') #3 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-settings.php(350): do_action('plugins_loaded') #6 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-config.php(86): require_once('/home1/thehub/p...') #7 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home1/thehub/p...') #8 /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/home1/ in /home1/thehub/public_html/theseen.org/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-links.php on line 17`

Comment: Can you add some context; what was going on before this happened, were you editing something, etc.  Step one is usually always to disable the plugins and also try switching back to the default theme.

Comment: The site was abandoned for some time... the error is not due to changes that I made it seems to just be something that wordpress auto updates didn't like.  I have tried to disable the plugin folder and receive the same error...it is a problem with the Widgets which do not seem to be a plugin, but more integral to WP.

Comment: That's not always exactly how it works; there is the possibility that the code executes properly within the file and only when WordPress' functionality becomes involved does the error then happen because of a conflict or dependency.  So what you get then is an error that it's something within WordPress but really the error is stemming from deprecated code.  If it's widget related you could also try switching to the default WordPress theme, you can do this by adding an underscore to the front of your theme directory via FTP '_theme-name'.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the `Class "WP_Widget" not found` error is caused by bot scans courtesy of script kiddies.

As suggested in a response to a [question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-fatal-error-in-the-log-file/) at WordPress, the scanning script will terminate when the following code is inserted at the top of `blocks/index.php`:

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH') || !defined('WPINC')) {
    exit;
}
```